# Ctrl + two chars

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, ctrl

I'm working on a python script to send data on a com port. The problem is, I need to send Ctrl+p+p (so on a keyboard, I'd stay on the Ctrl button and type twice the 'p' char), but I can't find a way to do this. I use the pyserial library.

Comment: What is Ctrl+p+p? What does it do? Where do you input that sequence when you are not using the script for that?

Comment: It's part of a sequence to activate logs on a TV. I do it with my keyboard in putty, since I can't use the script for now.

Comment: Do you want to capture ctrl+p+p in your script or do you want your script to transmit the same sequence as putty is doing when you press ctrl+p+p there?

Comment: I want the script to transmit it

Comment: Your wordings of *"Ctrl + two chars"* and *"Ctrl+p+p"* is part of your problem.  Instead of *"Ctrl + two chars"*, you seem to actually mean  *"two control chars"*.  Instead of *"Ctrl+p+p"*, you seem to actually mean  *"Ctrl+P"* followed by another  *"Ctrl+P"*,  aka `^P^P`.  The fact that you insist on not releasing the `Ctrl` between keystrokes is the root of your confusion.  The `Ctrl` key works just like the `Shift` key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking in an ascii table, e.g. [this](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html), you will see that ctrl+p is mapped to `0x10`. Thus, for your script to transmit ctrl+p, you need to transmit `0x10`.

Then transmitting ctrl+p+p (holding ctrl) is just the same value twice. Your script should therefore transmit `0x10 0x10` in sequence.